# Hyperledger fabric fabtoken energy certification use case

Tags: token, hyperledger-fabric

I'm developing a blockchain based system to provide energy certificates handled as tokens in hyperledger fabric. I've been doing some research but found no state of art on how to do this. If anyone can provide a useful link on how to bring this use case into hyperledger fabric tokens, I would be grateful. Also, I don't really know how to include the fabtoken functionality in an already deployed blockchain network. Any links or tips on how to start investigating for this will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fabtoken` was included in the fabric v2.0 alpha, but was reverted from git due to several issues. In other words, it is a method that is no longer supported.

Currently, fabric provides an example implemented in chaincode as a related token. See the link below.

- [fabric-samples/token-utxo](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/token-utxo)
- [fabric-samples/token-erc-20](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/token-erc-20)
- [fabric-samples/token-erc-721](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/token-erc-721)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was helpful. Also, do you happen to know of some energy certification use case that is based on any of these hyperledger approaches?

Comment: Sadly, I have no direct experience with energy certification. Particularly applicable to corporate solutions, but for energy, I attach the link I searched for. [Decentralized-energy-fabric](https://github.com/IBM/decentralized-energy-fabric-on-IBP20) / [Making-Renewable-Energy-Certificates](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/16140/Karakashev_Dimcho.pdf?sequence=5&isAllowed=y) / [blockchain-in-the-renewable-energy](https://4irelabs.com/cases/how-to-use-blockchain-technology-in-renewable-energy/)

Comment: [Virtual-Renewable-Energy-Blockchain-Network-Project](https://wiki.hyperledger.org/display/CASIG/Virtual+Renewable+Energy+Network+Project) with [hyperledger-carbon-accounting](https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/blockchain-carbon-accounting)

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. Also, you seem to know a lot about these token implementations in Fabric, I posted another question regarding token-UTXO here, in case you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67313253/hyperledger-fabric-token-utxo-does-not-implement-chaincode-interface