# Hyperledger fabric token UTXO does not implement chaincode interface

Tags: token, hyperledger-fabric

I'm new to Hyperledger Fabric, and trying to get into smart contract developing in Golang. Until now, all tutorials and sources I read said that a smart contract must always implement the chaincode interface:

```
type Chaincode interface {

Init (stub ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response Invoke (stub ChaincodeStubInterface) pb.Response

}
```

But it seems that the Hyperledger Fabric functionality for implementing token-UTXO: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/token-utxo
Is a smart contract which doesn't implement the methods `init` or `invoke` from the chaincode interface. See https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/token-utxo/chaincode-go/chaincode

Can anyone explain how is it possible that this chaincode works without implementing them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The newer Fabric samples such as the UTXO contract leverage the newer contract API. The newer contract API layer implements the init and invoke functions, while allowing user contracts to be written with a higher-level abstraction where the application's chaincode functions can be directly implemented in the contract.

For more details, see the [contract API documentation](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go/blob/main/tutorials/getting-started.md).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The thing is, I don't understand how come that Token UTXO doesn't implement neither init nor invoke functions and still works. What are those functions intended for? Is implementing them optional?